# What's another name for the sostenuto pedal?

Tags: piano, terminology

Every pedal except the sostenuto pedal also has an English name. Sostenuto means "sustained" in *Italian*, according to Wikipedia.

Another reason for an English word to replace the word "sostenuto" is that it has 4 syllables while the other pedal names have fewer (the *soft* pedal has 1, the *damper* pedal has 2)

Every other pedal has an English name. What's another name for the sostenuto? (Please make sure the name is in English.)

Comment: Soft pedal is the *una corda* pedal.(4 syllables!). Damper pedal actually does the opposite - it *undamps* the strings. Also called *sustain* pedal. Have never heard another name for the sostenuto pedal, which many uprights and some grands don't possess. Some have a *practice* pedal in the middle.

Comment: If you want to innovate, you could try the keepdown pedal, the rare pedal, the sos pedal (for short: "the sauce"), the [Claire de] Lune pedal... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've heard it referred to as the "sustain pedal" plenty of times.

(This looks like way too short of an answer, but I don't see how to beef it up...)

Comment: If the middle pedal is the sustain, then what's the right hand (foot!) one called?

Comment: @Tim Yikes, I just realized that I completely misunderstood the question! Part of me wants to delete my answer, but apparently at least three people *also* call the middle pedal the sustain pedal...?!

Answer (score 3):

Nope, just 'Sostenuto pedal'.   The only alternative might be 'middle pedal' - but a middle pedal can be other things.